# Nhibernate incrementally saving binary data

Tags: c#, nhibernate, binary-data, large-object-heap

Following up from [Avoiding the LOH when reading a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781521/avoiding-the-loh-when-reading-a-binary)

In Nhibernate would it be possible to save a `Stream` to database in chunks?

With the following code, a FileStream is opened and its contents are read in 2kb chunks:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        //// somehow push the contents of the buffer to the database        
    }
}
```

Usually objects are persisted in one operation, can it be done incrementally?